# creat-react-app build not accepting styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am moving my react app from self managed webpack build to a `create-react-app` based one. My styles are not compiling correctly, for example, in my main render method:

```
      return (
        <Grid>
            <Row style={headerStyle}>
                <Col xs={12}>
                <h1 style={{'text-align': 'center', 'color': 'white'}}>
                    Dashboard v0.3 
                </h1>
                </Col>
            </Row>
       </Grid>
       )
```

I get the error `Warning: Unsupported style property text-align. Did you mean textAlign?`. There are a bunch of errors like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When using inline styles or JS styles you can't have dashes in property names, because it's an object. So `text-align` becomes `textAlign`, or `border-top` becomes `borderTop`, and so on

Comment: my point is that before in my old system it was transpiled correctly but now it doesn't

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong syntax. It should be like this:

```
<h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}} >
```

Comment: my point is that before in my old system it was transpiled correctly but now it doesn't

Comment: idk which version of react you used in your old system but AFAIK text-align will throw an error in the latest react versions.

Answer (score 1):

In react css work like the following:

```js
<div style={{
    fontFamily: 'Consolas',
    padding: 10,
    color: "#444",
    border: "3px solid orange",
    position: "relative",
    width: "15%",
    height: "25px",
    letterSpacing: 0,
    overflow: "hidden",
    fontSize: 10,
    fontVariant: "small-caps"
}}
>
Hello
</div>
```

not like this

```js
<div style="font-family: Consolas;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #444;
    border: none;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%; height: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-variant: small-caps;"
>
text
</div>
```

I hope this would help